# Take a value + append a link tag with that value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-blade

I am retrieving links to different pages and what I want to do is if user clicks on one of these links,  tag will be appended to html page with href which is stored as a value.

So then in html page link will display and once clicked it will take to the page that user has choosen. So basically I want to be able for user to create their own navigation bar.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
@foreach ($websites as $website)
<li><a class="websites" value=" {{ url('website/' . $website->name) }}"> {{  $website->name }}
</a></li> @endforeach
</div>
```

So I have started creating a function however it adds all links how to a trim it so only one is appended?

```
$(".websites").on('click', function() {
    $(".websites").appendTo("#content-link2");
});
```

Comment: You're probably missing a tag on your question - maybe mention what template engine you're using for the `foreach` functionality :)

Comment: Laravel blade, I have added a tag, thanks